# How to center a plot with outside legends

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I would like to center a plot with outside legends, but the whole figure gets centered (plot with legends). The position of the plot should be like the outside legend is not there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
  xmin=0.01,xmax=100,
  ymin=0,ymax=5,
  width=8cm,
  legend style={at={(1.03,0.5)},anchor=west,draw=none},
  legend cell align={left},
  grid]
  \addplot[red,domain=0.01:100,samples=400]{(2)/(1+x^2)};
  \addplot[blue,domain=0.01:100,samples=400]{(1+x^2)/(1-x^2+x^4)};
  \legend{$Q=0.5$,$Q=1$}
  \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Looks like:
[image]

But should look like this (of course with the outside legend added):
[image]

Comment: Welcomme. Please make your code compileable.

Comment: Sure, i edited the code.

Comment: You can either add extra space to the left, or risk overlapping to the right.

Comment: @Marius Note that you can change  `legend style={at={(0.6,0.8)},anchor=west,draw=none}` to put legends inside the rectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the simplest way to achieve what you want is to simply add `overlay` to the `legend style` options. This prevents that the legend is accounted for in the determination of the bounding box.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            xmin=0.01,xmax=100,
            ymin=0,ymax=5,
            width=8cm,
            legend style={
                overlay,        % <-- added
                at={(1.03,0.5)},
                anchor=west,
                draw=none,
            },
            legend cell align={left},
            grid,
            domain=0.01:100,samples=400,
        ]
            \addplot [red]  {(2)/(1+x^2)};
            \addplot [blue] {(1+x^2)/(1-x^2+x^4)};
            \legend{$Q=0.5$,$Q=1$}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: thanks, it worked well!

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Of course Zarko's answer is also perfectly fine, so it would also be ok if you mark his answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you looking for the following?

[image]

(red lines designate text borders)

For this you only need to add to `tikzpicture` the option `trim axis left, trim axis right`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right] % <-------
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
  xmin=0.01,xmax=100,
  ymin=0,ymax=5,
  width=8cm,
  legend style={at={(1.03,0.5)},anchor=west,draw=none},
  legend cell align={left},
  grid]
  \addplot[red,domain=0.01:100,samples=400]{(2)/(1+x^2)};
  \addplot[blue,domain=0.01:100,samples=400]{(1+x^2)/(1-x^2+x^4)};
  \legend{$Q=0.5{}$,$Q=1$}
  \end{semilogxaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Lorem Ipsum}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was also my idea, but it would even be better if you also add `trim axis left` to the `tikzpicture` options. This is especially true the wider the `xticklabels` are and/or if a `ylabel` is present.

Comment: ... And of course this solution only works if you don't `external`ize the plots.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, you are right. I corrected my answer. About eventual externalizing of  image OP didn't provide any information.